# Android Studio ¿Como capturar la tecla enter?

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard

**Descripción:**

Tengo una ventana de registro en la cual quiero que, al tocar el **Enter** del teclado, la selección de edit Text, cambie al siguiente.

**Pregunta:**

¿Como capturo la selección del enter para después poder cambiar la seleccion del edit text?

**Adjunto código java con el cual probé pero no funcionó:**

```
et_nombre.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                Toast.makeText(alumno_datos_personales.this, "Enter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Adjunto el código XML de mi edit text**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_nombre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/if_background_et_log_reg"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:hint="@string/nombre_completo"
    android:textColor="#4D4C4C"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:fontFamily="@font/source_sans_pro_regular"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_lore" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Básicamente tienes que detectar si el Keycode es `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER`, pero en este caso debes usar el listener [OnEditorActionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener)

```
    et_nombre.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

            Toast.makeText(alumno_datos_personales.this, "Enter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Para esto debes tener definido en tu `EditText` :

`android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

Comment: En esta línea de código: "if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){"  me marca que está el siguiente error: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.KeyEvent.getKeyCode()' on a null object reference" que puede ser?

Comment: Ah event puede ser null, no lo recordaba, revisa la actualización @TomasM

Comment: @TomasM como realizas el "ENTER", estas usando un teclado? como esta configurado en el XML tu EditText?

Comment: Actualizé la pregunta con el código xml de mi edit text. Estoy usando el enter del keyboard

Comment: Ok revisa mi actualización, es importante definas android:imeOption. @TomasM

Comment: Finalmente funcionó. Gracias infinitas nuevamente Jorge. Si no te molesta, podrías revisar otras de mis preguntas que están sin responder? Me sería de gran ayuda